# Calling a 2010 workflow from an app step

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I am trying to start a 2010 workflow (which involves sending an email) from within an 'app step' (i.e. elevated permissions) of a 2013 workflow. However, I am an 'access denied - you do not have permission to access this resource' message.

The workflow runs fine if that particular step which requires starting the 2010 workflow is not invoked. Therefore I concluded, that the app step is not able to start the 2010 workflow. Does anyone here has any thoughts on how can I get around this?

Many thanks

Comment: You ever find a solution for this? Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

**It's by design,**

The `Start a List Workflow` action **only** run the SharePoint 2010 workflow,

[image]

Unfortunately, the SharePoint 2010 workflow is **not supported** in **App step** in SharePoint Workflow 2013.

---

**Alternatives**

- [Using a REST call to start a workflow](http://www.benprins.net/2016/12/30/sharepoint-2013-workflow-start-a-workflow-using-a-rest-call/),
- Instead of running the SharePoint 2010 workflow, try to create a remote Event Receiver on a specific event like `ItemAdded` or `ItemUpdated` to simulate the same workflow behavior!

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any workaround?

Comment: Kindly, check the updated answer!

Comment: The article you quoted talks about starting a 2013 workflow. Can this same method be used for starting a 2010 workflow?

Comment: No bro, it's only for SP 2013 WF

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from you desciption if you have activated the App step feature on the site. If you have done that have you also granted full permission to the workflow "app" by entering the xml in appinv.aspx?

If not that most properly is the reason as the app hasn't been granted any permission to actually start the workflow.

Grab the id of the workflow under "Site app permissions"
Visit /_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
Enter the following xml (no placeholders just insert the actual code):

```
 <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

The full guide to do it is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: I had already activated the App step feature by giving full permissions before I posted this question. As I said, the workflow works fine if the step that involves calling the 2010 workflow is not executed.

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem (no solution yet though). It seems that an action to start a 2010 workflow from within an App step is invalid.

Comment: what's the meaning of "calling the 2010 workflow is not executed"? Could you tell us how you set steps in app steps and steps in 2010 workflow?

Comment: There absolutely no problem in starting a 2010 workflow from within a 2013 app step. I have several usecases where I'm doing exactly that. But it does require the workflow to have the correct permissions.

Comment: @MortenK SPD is not giving me an option to place an action to start a 2010 workflow within an app step. I can do it outside the app step. When I place the action outside the app step and move it up inside the app step, I get an error when saving/publishing the workflow.

Comment: Sound strange - I have it working on one of my clients on a 2016 on premise installation.